# ADO.net SQL Server mystery with case sensitivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

All this on the same server of my client.

I have one database, let's say I called it `MYDATABASE` in SQL Server.

I have 2 ASP.Net Web apps that are exactly the same, one is just a copy of the other with some modifications for testing and will replace the other.

Everything works except for one place where a query is executed. The query has the name of the database in small caps. Web App 1 executes fine, Web App 2 throws an exception

> Invalid object name mydatabase...

I cannot modify the query since it's in a third party DLL.

Comment: Are both web apps running on the same version of .NET?

Comment: Good question, I'll check once I get in conctact with my client.

Answer (score 2):

You need check and may be modify the SQL Server Collations. Collations specify the rules for how strings of character data are sorted and compared.

May be your servers are not with the same Collation values.

First, run this command

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')
```

The result string must contains **'CI'** for **"Case Insensitive"** or maybe 'CS' for "Case Sensitive".

Find here an article to know your collations and how to change that: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2901/how-to-change-server-level-collation-for-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: What's weird is that the two ASP.net apps are running on the same server. They're querying the same server. I will check anyways. Thanks.

Comment: One of the apps may either have magic strings that match the database or be focing a caseing change.  The other app might also be using something like LINQ to Objects so it is doing hte queries in memory which then .Net string comparison rules apply.